# How to use an order_by clause on a rails scope that handles null values

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to order some values that I get back from a query. The scope is as follows:

`scope :complete, -> {where(status:[Status::SOLD, Status::NO_SALE])}`

In an API I return `a.items.complete` which is call the above query. I need to modify this call by adding an `order` clause based on two attributes: `starts_at` and `scheduled_end_time` in descending order. So I tried the following but and getting an error:

`items = items.complete.order("CASE WHEN items.actual_end_time IS NULL THEN items.starts_at ELSE items.scheduled_end_time END DESC")`

**ERROR:**
`` {"error":"Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'items.starts_at' in 'order clause': SELECT  `items`.* FROM `items` WHERE `items`.`company_id` = 2 AND `items`.`status` IN ('sold', 'no_sale')  ORDER BY CASE WHEN scheduled_end_time IS NULL THEN starts_at ELSE scheduled_end_time END DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0"} ``

I am trying to determine how to check if scheduled_end_time is null and if so order by the starts_at...If I strip of the DESC at the end it works, but I need them to be descending. Any help or pointers is appreciated.

Auctions have many Items for what its worth.

**Auctions schema:**

[image]

**Items schema:**

[image]

Comment: Isn't the comma before `DESC` unnecessary?

Comment: @NicNilov I think you might be right...updated the question

Comment: Please add your table's schema.

Comment: @NicNilov So I think I found my problem....the starts_at is part of the auction...and auction has many items...is there anyway that I can reference that?

Comment: At this point you just have to show your tables' schema.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116597/discussion-between-zack-herbert-and-nic-nilov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the order fields by their full names:

```
items = items.complete.order("CASE WHEN items.scheduled_end_time IS NULL THEN items.starts_at ELSE items.scheduled_end_time END DESC")
```

**UPDATE**

You could use `COALESCE` and multiple `order` clauses to get there. Also, you need to join the `auctions`. Something along these lines:

```
items.complete.
    joins(:auctions).
    order("COALESCE(auctions.scheduled_end_time, date('01-01-1970')) DESC").
    order("COALESCE(auctions.starts_at, date('01-01-1970')) DESC")
```

`COALESCE` replace `NULL`'s with it's first non-null argument so the field is treated like having a value during the ordering. Depending on whether you want `NULL`s on bottom or on top, pass a value beyond the lowest or highest range boundary of your data, respectively.

I'm not sure whether MySQL supports the `date('01-01-1970')` syntax, maybe it's something like `CAST('01-01-1970' AS DATETIME)`, but the approach should be valid.

Another, cleaner approach would be to explicitly sort each field by `NULL` first:

```
items.complete.
    joins(:auctions).
    order("auctions.scheduled_end_time IS NULL, auctions.scheduled_end_time DESC").
    order("auctions.starts_at IS NULL, auctions.starts_at DESC")
```

Comment: still getting the same error `Unknown column 'scheduled_end_time'`

Comment: yeah this is exactly what I ended up doing

Answer (score 1):

Remove the , before the DESC keyword. The SQL interpreter is not able to interpret this properly due to the existence of the ,. Once you remove that it should work properly.

Comment: you are right but @NicNilov has a more complete answer...thanks for your help